# how to place the UI behind the GameObject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to place the UI behind the Game Object.
Is there a useful unity settings?

Comment: Change UI Canvas Render Mode to World Space and then you can position it as any other Game Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please include a specific example from your project so we can give a better answer.

Generally speaking though, you can use Canvas Render Mode: "World" or "Screen Space - Camera" to render UI behind a 3D GameObject.

The method you choose depends on your specific needs.